# Testing nested objects as undefined in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, properties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript test for existence of nested object key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/javascript-test-for-existence-of-nested-object-key)

I'm attempting to construct an error message for a `formset` by testing if a certain object is *not* `undefined`, and if it's not `undefined`, then I end up populating it with that error message. The main problem is that I have to validate if each nested object is `undefined`, which results in some pretty ugly code. Here's the example:

```
errorsForField: function(fieldName, formsetName, formNumber) {
            if (typeof this.model.errors != 'undefined'){

                var fieldError = document.createElement('span');
                $(fieldError).addClass('field-error');

                // THE FOLLOWING LINE THROWS ERROR.
                if (formsetName && _.isUndefined(this.model.errors[formsetName][fieldName]) != true) {
                    $(fieldError).text(this.model.errors[formsetname][fieldName]);
                } else if (typeof this.model.errors[fieldName] != "undefined"){
                    $(fieldError).text(this.model.errors[fieldName]);
                }

                this.errors[fieldName] = fieldError.outerHTML;
                return fieldError.outerHTML; 
            }
            return false; 
        },
```

I get an error stating that I cannot determine `[fieldName]` of an `undefined object` `this.model.errors[formsetName]`. In other words, I have to first determine if `this.model.errors[formsetName]` is empty and *then* test if `[fieldname]` is `undefined`.

This seems like a really cumbersome solution. Any suggestions for changing this?

Comment: I've never seen a solution to this problem in pure JavaScript.  This is called "safe navigation" or "soaking up nulls" by the way. Coffeescript, which boils down to JS, has this feature. You may want to look at their implementation for inspiration; it seems to use a lot of ternary operators. The [overview of Coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/) has an example. Search that page for "soaking up nulls"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a library function that takes property names as parameters and returns the final value if it exists, or null:

```
function TryGetPropertyValue(o, propertyName1 /*, ... propertyNameN */) {
    var names = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    while (o && names.length) {
        o = o[names.shift()];
    }
    return names.length ? null : o;
}
```

Call it like:

```
var err = TryGetPropertyValue(this.model.errors, formsetName, fieldName) ||
          TryGetPropertyValue(this.model.errors, fieldName);
if (err != null) {
    $(fieldError).text(err);
}
```

If you want it to return `undefined` instead of `null` if the field is not found, you can change the function slightly:

```
function TryGetPropertyValue(o, propertyName1 /*, ... propertyNameN */) {
    var names = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    while (o && names.length) {
        o = o[names.shift()];
    }
    if (names.length == 0) {
        return o;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HbggQ/

Comment: Is it possible get property value by passing just property name (not by path). For Example by passing 'isValid' propery name it should get all occurances of 'isValid'

Comment: @Narendra - you can write a function that walks objects looking for properties, but you can quickly get into trouble if, for example, the object contains a circular reference or a reference to `window`.

Answer (score 3):

As Paul suggested, this is an inherent limitation of Javascript.  Even Coffeescript (which is just a layer of syntactic sugar on top of JS) doesn't really *solve* the problem; it just hides the workaround under it's syntactic sugar (which admittedly is really handy)

If you want to stick to Javascript, you basically have two options: use ternary operators, or use boolean operators.  Here's examples of each that check A.B.C.D (where A, B, C or D might not exist):

```
// Returns A.B.C.D, if it exists; otherwise returns false (via ternary)
return !A ? false :
            !A.B ? false :
                   !A.B.C ? false :
                            A.B.C.D ? A.B.C.D : false;

// Returns A.B.C.D, if it exists; otherwise returns false (via booleans)
return A && A.B && A.B.C && A.B.C.D;
```

Obviously the latter is a lot shorter.  Both solutions rely on Javascript's "truthiness" (ie. that the values `0`, `""`, `null`, and `undefined` count as false).  This should be fine for your case, as none of those values will have an errors property.  However, if you did need to distinguish between (say) `0` and `undefined`, you could use the ternary style, and replace `!A` with `typeof(A) == 'undefined'`.